# Prepared eclipse with famous plugins / known good configurations

Tags: eclipse

I've just set up my machine from scratch and was wondering if there are any open available ready to use Eclipse versions (3.5 preferred) which have already installed famous (most used) plugins like subversion support, maven, pmd, checkstyle, findbugs etc. This would save me time setting it up myself.

thx,

kuku

Answer (score 2):

Never really tried it myself, but this may ease it up for you: [yoxos](http://ondemand.yoxos.com/geteclipse/start)
And then there's [myeclipseide](http://myeclipseide.com/) but I think you pay for it.

Comment: i think it's a pretty good idear to do something like this. For example it would be guranteed that a team works with the same IDE plugins/configurations and so on. I pretty sure that many do something similar like this already but i did not find anything online. I'm looking for something free but thx anyway :)

Comment: I'd look again at Yoxos. After a registration you could create your own set of plug-ins, that you can share with your co-workers.
The big thing with Yoxos is that the packages are not readymade, but you could create them this way.

Answer (score 1):

For making sure everyone on our team works with the same set of plugins, we are using the notion of ["group of plugins" in a Nexus Pro (so non-free) repository](http://live.eclipse.org/node/696)

> Nexus Professional has support for Eclipse P2 repositories, and it can serve Eclipse plugin artifacts to tools that know how to interact with the Eclipse P2 repository format including Eclipse 3.4 Ganymede.
>
> If you use the Eclipse IDE, you probably have a set of plugins which every single developer needs to install to get productive.
>   Using Nexus Professional, you can combine multiple Eclipse update sites into a single URL which your developers can use when they are configuring a development environment.
>
> Using Nexus Professional as a single point-of-access between your developers and the Eclipse update sites they depend on allows you to manage and define a set of common Eclipse plugins in your organization's Eclipse development environment.